# How to find E1 value in cloumn2 and then replace by column1 value using macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the value available in `E1` cell into `column2` rows and then replace by `column1` value. For e.g.

B2 value should be replaced from ABC-1 to A-1.
B3 value should be replaced from ABC-1 to B-1

and so on.

I am new in macros.

I was trying to put the code from internet

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()

Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant  

fnd = "ABC"
rplc = Cells(i, 8).Value

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Then
          Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more and share few screenshot of how want it to perform ?

Comment: You are using `i` (`rplc = Cells(i, 8).Value`) before you start the loop with `i`.

Comment: Column1 Column2   ABC
A ABC-1   
B ABC-2   
C ABC-3   
D ABC-4   
E ABC-5   
F ABC-6   
G ABC-7   
H ABC-8   
I ABC-9   
J ABC-10

Comment: I couldn't be able to find how to paste the screenshot. Column1 contains values as A, B, C, D, E and column 2 as ABC-1, ABC-2, ABC-3 and so on. There is value in E1 column as ABC

Answer (score 1):

Edited your code a bit to suit the needs you described (if understood correctly)

- You are always searching for the value in absolute cell `E1`
- You replace the searchvalue in column B with the full value from column A

My sample data based on your comments:

[image]

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()

Dim fnd As String, rplc As String, i As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Your sheetname goes here
    fnd = .Range("E1").Value
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(i, 2).Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

After running macro:

[image]

And in case you can just do this through formula and avoid VBA (especially if you are new to that), for example in `C2` put:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,(SEARCH("-",B2)-1))=$E$1,A2&RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-SEARCH("-",B2)+1),B2)
```

And drag down...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See comments in the code for more details, but let me know if this does what you are asking:

```vb
Sub FindReplaceAll()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name") '<-- set your sheet name
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row in column A
Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = ws.Range("A1:E" & lRow) 'declare and allocate data to an array

Dim R As Long, C As Long

For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
    If arrData(R, 5) = arrData(R, 2) Then 'if E matches the value in B
    'If arrData(1, 5) = arrData(R, 2) Then 'Alternative if E1 is a fixed value, and not for every row
        ws.Cells(R, 2) = arrData(R, 1) 'allocate the A value to B
    End If
Next R

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindReplaceAll()

    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Set the SearchString equal to the value of cell E1
        SearchString = .Range("E1").Value

        'Loop from second row to lastrow
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            'If the value of cell B & i equal to SearchString
            If (.Range("B" & i).Value <> "") And (.Range("B" & i).Value = SearchString) Then
                'Cell B & i equal to A & i
                .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```